codeigniter page title not changed
i am trying to change the page title in codeigniter but no luck to change the the title, seem to be stuck in the old name.
the page controller php file
 public function index() {
        $data['nurse'] = "Welcome to codigniter";
        $this->load->view('home/dashboard'); 
        $this->load->view('nurse', $data);
        $this->load->view('home/footer'); 
    }

the page view php file
<section id="main-content">
    <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
         <link href="common/extranal/css/nurse.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <section class="panel">
            <header class="panel-heading">
                Technicians
                <div class="col-md-4 no-print pull-right"> 
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
                        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                            <button id="" class="btn green btn-xs">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Add Technician
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </header>
            <title><?php echo $page_title; ?> </title>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="adv-table editable-table ">
                    <div class="space15"></div>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="editable-sample">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><?php echo lang('image'); ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo lang('name'); ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo lang('email'); ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo lang('address'); ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo lang('phone'); ?></th>
                                <th class="no-print"><?php echo lang('options'); ?></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

i used this code in the view file
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?> </title>

but still no change, how to change the title

If you want so have a $page_title variable with the value "Welcome to codigniter" in your view, you need to change $data['nurse'] = "Welcome to codigniter"; to $data['page_title'] = "Welcome to codigniter"; in your controller.

There should be only one  element in an HTML document located inside the  section
